# How to understand the source code of Jitsi to modify or add some features as per requirements

Tags: jitsi-meet

I would like to modify/customize the Jitsi. For that, I would like to
understand the calls involved and other interfaces communicating with each other.
It would be a great help if anyone suggests what is the best way to proceed or
any code browsing and call graph generation tools. Also, it would be a great
help to know, what is the best way to set up a development and test environment
for all the components(prosody, jicofo, jvb, jibri, jigasi etc.) involved.